# MSSQL datetime to SOLR date using ColdFusion

Tags: sql-server, solr, coldfusion

My query has a field CONTENTDISPLAYDATE and cfdump displays it as "2014-10-16 00:00:00.0". I add it to the SOLR collection using contentdisplaydate_dt="ContentDisplayDate" in my cfindex statement. 
When I cfdump the resulting data from the cfsearch result, the field appears as "Thu Oct 16 00:00:00 EDT 2014" and sorting on it doesn't work. Using query of queries on the resultset and ordering by it also doesn't work. So looks like assigning it to a SOLR date field isn't working. Can anyone shed light on what I'm doing wrong? We're using the default version of SOLR that ships with CF 10.

Comment: in your Solr index, is the field `contentdisplaydate_dt` defined as a date field? What does the content of that date look like when you query Solr directly via its web service? `http://mysolrserver:8983/solr/myindex/select?q=searchterm&fl=contentdisplaydate_dt` (Just trying to figure out whether the weirdness is happening at index time or query time ... if the former, you'll see the "Thu Oct 16..." dates in the data returned by the web service.)

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you. CF was doing something to the index date, which was in the correct format.

Comment: I don't think CF would recognize a Solr date as a date without some manipulation.

Comment: Trying to mark your answer as an answer but it doesnt seem to want to let me do that.

Comment: BTW your website is awesome for ColdFusion/SOLR information

Comment: With your permission I'll add the above as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do would be to check to make sure that the field `contentdisplaydate_dt` is defined as a date field in Solr. You can do this by looking at the file **schema.xml** under this particular collection (often **C:\ColdFusion9\collections\mycollection\conf\**).

You can also confirm the content of `contentdisplaydate_dt` by querying the Solr index directly in your browser (using the Solr web service):

```
http://mysolrserver:8983/solr/myindex/select?q=searchterm&fl=contentdisplaydate‌​_dt
```

(The above URL will return XML data by default; if you prefer JSON then add `&wt=json` to the URL.)

My guess is that what is happening is that ColdFusion is trying to convert the Solr dates (which are always of the format `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ`) and the results aren't pretty. You have to do some manipulation in order to convert Solr dates to a date format recognized by CF.

Last, I would encourage you to use Solr's web service both to index and to search your data rather than using `<cfindex>` and `<cfsearch>`. Searching is especially easy with the Solr web service; just use `<cfhttp>` to call the web service and `deserializeJSON()` to process the data returned (assuming you're returning JSON instead of XML).